# Using Python to import CSV, amend, and export new CSV

Tags: python

Basically what I'm trying to do is input a CSV file, change some information on each row, then create a new output file

My python is definitely the beginner level so apologizes if below is stupid - my head is currently hitting a wall

Below is where I've got to but am coming up with various problems - any ideas how to do it?

```
import csv
file_1 = 'input.csv'
with open('output.csv',"w+") as write_file:
        writer=csv.writer(write_file)
        with open(file_1) as data_1:
                reader=csv.reader(data_1)
                for row in reader:
                        writer.writerows([row[0].replace(',','')],row[1],[row[4].replace('\n','')])
```

Comment: Can you specify what problems you are facing?

Comment: What problems are you running into? You can also read [this](https://realpython.com/python-csv/) tutorial on python and csv files. Good luck.

Comment: your question has the right order of operations. your code doesn't. first read the csv. then modify. only then open the output csv and export to it. Heck, a recommendation. Just read, and modify. figure out how to write it back later. use print statements to see how things are going.

Comment: Take a look at the docs. Note the difference between "writerows" and "writerow" and take a look what is expected to be a row. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects

Comment: Thanks All - I'll go through and come back with more detail and changes based on links and advice you've provided. Step by step :)